# React HOC with TypeScript: could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

What I'm trying to do is to write a HOC, which wraps a component with a mandatory property `value`, but doesn't pass through its own property `name`

```js
  import React, { ComponentType } from 'react';
  
  interface IPassThroughProps {
    value: string;
  }
  
  interface IHocPropsType {
    name: string;
  }
  
  export function hoc<PropsType extends IPassThroughProps>(
    Component: ComponentType<PropsType>
  ): ComponentType<IHocPropsType & PropsType> {
    const hoc = ({ name, ...props }: IHocPropsType & PropsType): JSX.Element => (
      <Component {...props} />
    );
    return hoc;
  }
```

The issue is that typing error is generated:

> Type `Pick<IHocPropsType & PropsType, Exclude<keyof PropsType, "name">>` is not assignable to type `IntrinsicAttributes & PropsType & { children?: ReactNode; }`.
>
> Type `Pick<IHocPropsType & PropsType, Exclude<keyof PropsType, "name">>` is not assignable to type `PropsType`.
>
> `Pick<IHocPropsType & PropsType, Exclude<keyof PropsType, "name">>` is assignable to the constraint of type `PropsType`, but `PropsType` could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint `IPassThroughProps`.

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

I think I need to do something with this bit:

`IHocPropsType & PropsType`

But not quite have an idea of how to express it.

Comment: I think it means that we can't exclude a field from generic

Answer (score 3):

A proper way to fix it is type-casting of `...props` along with using an `Omit` util:

```
  import React, { ComponentType } from 'react';

  interface IPassThroughProps {
    value: string;
  }

  interface IHocPropsType {
    name: string;
  }

  export function hoc<PropsType extends IPassThroughProps>(
    Component: ComponentType<PropsType>
  ): ComponentType<IHocPropsType & Omit<PropsType, 'name'>> => {
    const hoc = (
      { name, ...props }: IHocPropsType & Omit<PropsType, 'name'>
    ): JSX.Element => (
      <Component {...(props as PropsType)} />
    );
    return hoc;
  }
```

Comment: I'm doing something similar where my HOC provides an overridable default for certain properties, did you find a pattern which didn't rely on `as T` ?